# How to write a toCSV method for scala case class that would generate the csv string for the class?

Tags: scala, csv

I have a **scala case class** that is something like below.

```
case class Address(
              city: Option[String] = None,
              country: Option[String] = None
                )
case class Student(
              id: Option[String] = None,
              name: Option[String] = None,
              address: Option[Seq[Address]] = None,
              phone: Option[Seq[String]] = None
                )
```

Now I want to write a **toCSV** method for student that would generate a **list of csv strings/lines** for each student. I am unable to determine how to generate string format for fields that can have multiple values such as: address and phone.

For a student,

```
val student_1 = Student(
              id = Some("1"),
              name = Some("john"),
              address = Some(Seq(
                         Address(Some("Newyork"),Some("USA")),
                         Address(Some("Berlin"),Some("Germany")),
                         Address(Some("Tokyo"),Some("Japan")),
                         )),
              phone = Some(Seq(
                         "1111","9999","8888"
                         ))
              )
```

So, **student_1.toCSV** must result in following **csv string**:

```
id, name, address.city, address.country, phone
1 , John, Newyork     , USA            , 1111/9999/888
  ,     , Berlin      , Germany        , 
  ,     , Tokyo       , Japan          ,
```

This is the csv list of string where first string represents the first row and so on.I need to generate this list of strings for each student. Note that there could be multiple lines for each student because address and phones can have multiple values.In this case, there are 3 addresses and 2 phones for student John.
How do I achieve this in scala ?

**Addition:**

So far, I am working to produce a List of csv lines i.e a list of Lists where each list would store one row.
So, the list would look like below:

```
List(
    List("id","name","address.city","address.country","phone"),
    List("1" ,"John","Newyork"     ,"USA"            ,"11111/22222"),
    List(""  ,""    ,"Berlin"      ,"Germany"        ,""),
    List(""  ,""    ,"Tokyo"       ,"Japan"          ,"")
    )
```

Comment: Anything that you have tried already?  A sample implementation of `toCSV` would help.

Hints:  Think of `getOrElse` type functions and String formatting.  Scala is pretty powerful in that case.

Comment: The proposed layout associates the 1st address with the 1st phone number, the 2nd address with the 2nd phone number, etc. That arrangement might be misleading.

Comment: Just itterate through the 4 fields, when they are empty add nothing + "," when they are full add value + "," and when you've itterate through all of them once add a "\n" .... that's basically the answer to your question, at least that's what your current wording makes it sound like.

Comment: @jwvh I have modified the format for the phone number. Please suggest if you have some better structure in mind :)

Comment: @George I cam looking to generate a csv string for a single student only, not for list of students. So, how can I iterate though four fields ? I can only iterate through fields : address, phone  because they are lists.

Comment: @oblivion You are welcome.  Do try and post the code, the more we share the more we learn.  You will get good code review tips on here.

Answer (score 1):

In this I simplified your `Address` type to just a `String`, and I kept the `phone` layout as you had it originally (i.e. the one I complained about in the comments). So this is more of a proof-of-concept rather than a finished product.

```
val student = Student(Some("1")
  , Some("John")
  , Some(Seq("Newyork", "Berlin", "Tokyo"))
  , Some(Seq("1111","9999"))
)

student match {
  case Student(i,n,a,p) => 
    val maxLen = a.getOrElse(Seq("")).length max p.getOrElse(Seq("")).length
    Seq( Seq(i.getOrElse("")).padTo(maxLen,"")
       , Seq(n.getOrElse("")).padTo(maxLen,"")
       , a.getOrElse(Seq()).padTo(maxLen,"")
       , p.getOrElse(Seq()).padTo(maxLen,"")
       ).transpose
}
// res0: Seq[Seq[String]] = List( List(1, John, Newyork, 1111)
//                              , List(, , Berlin, 9999)
//                              , List(, , Tokyo, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by @jwvh above,

I have come up with a solution which is working for me now:

```
val student_1 = Student(
id = Some("1"),
name = Some("john"),
address = Some(Seq(
  Address(Some("Newyork"),Some("USA")),
  Address(Some("Berlin"),Some("Germany")),
  Address(Some("Tokyo"),Some("Japan"))
)),
phone = Some(Seq(
  "1111","9999","8888"
))
)

 def csvHeaders:List[String] = {
    List("StudentId","Name","Address.City","Address.Province","Phones")
 }

 def toCSV:List[List[String]] ={
   val maximumLength = address.getOrElse(Seq.empty[Address]).length max    1 
  //phone.getOrElse(Seq.empty[String]).length for earlier case where phones were kept in separate rows , done by @jwvh above
   val idList = List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => "    ").updated(0,id.getOrElse(""))
   val nameList = List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => "    ").updated(0,name.getOrElse(""))
   val addressCityList = if(address.isDefined){
    address.get.map{
    k => k.city.getOrElse(" ")
    }.toList.padTo(maximumLength," ")
    } else{
    List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => " ")
    }
    val addressProvinceList = if(address.isDefined){
    address.get.map{
    k => k.province.getOrElse(" ")
    }.toList.padTo(maximumLength," ")
    } else{
    List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => " ")
    }
    val phoneList = if(phone.isDefined){
    List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => "     ").updated(0,phone.get.padTo(maximumLength," ").mkString("/"))
    } else{
    List.tabulate(maximumLength)(k => " ")
    }
    val transposedList:List[List[String]] =     List(idList,nameList,addressCityList,addressProvinceList,phoneList).transpose

    transposedList.+:(csvHeaders)
 }

So, now student_1.toCSV will return:

 /*   List(
        List(StudentId, Name, Address.City, Address.Province,      Phones),      
        List(1, john, Newyork, USA, 1111/9999/8888), 
        List( ,  , Berlin, Germany,  ), 
        List( ,  , Tokyo, Japan,  )
       ) */
```